# adding a many to many relationship between two object in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, database, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am making an application with these two models

```
public class Operator
{
    //attributes
    public virtual ICollection<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }

}

public class Merchant
{
    //attributes
    public virtual ICollection<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
}
```

code first approach with this DbContext derived class.

```
 public class ContextClass : DbContext
 {
     public ContextClass() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
     {

     }
     public virtual DbSet<Operator> Operators { get; set; }
     public virtual DbSet<Merchant> Merchants { get; set; }
    //public object Merchant { get; internal set; }
}
```

I have established a connection in the database and successfully ran seeding.
now i am trying to make a new relationship between two other objects that have no relationship using this function

```
ContextClass _db = new ContextClass();
public bool createRelationShip(int MerchantId, int OperatorId)
    {
        var _mm = new MerchantManager();
        var _om = new OperatorManager();
        var _merchat = _mm.GetMerchant(MerchantId);//gets merchant object 
        var _operator = _om.GetOperator(OperatorId);//gets operator object 
        if (_merchat != null && _operator != null)
        {

            _merchat.Operators.Add(_operator);//supposed to create relationship
                                            //the same way as I did in seeding
             _db.Merchants.Add(_merchat);
            //what next??
            return true;
        }
        return false
    }
```

I can't figure out how to add the relationship to the database.

Comment: U need mapping table (poco class) to create `many-to-many` rel in EF

Comment: I already have a OperatorMerchant Table, i am trying to adding value the to the table

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to add a Merchant with an id that already exists.  You established the relationship with

```
_merchat.Operators.Add(_operator);
```

Remove the line

```
_db_Merchants.Add(_merchat);
```

and replace with

```
_db.SaveChanges();
```